# How to flatten a list of lists?

Tags: r, list, tm

The `tm` package extends `c` so that, if given a set of `PlainTextDocument`s it automatically creates a `Corpus`. Unfortunately, it appears that each `PlainTextDocument` must be specified separately.

e.g. if I had:

```
foolist <- list(a, b, c); # where a,b,c are PlainTextDocument objects
```

I'd do this to get a `Corpus`:

```
foocorpus <- c(foolist[[1]], foolist[[2]], foolist[[3]]);
```

I have a list of lists of `'PlainTextDocument`s that looks like this:

```
> str(sectioned)
List of 154
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ :Classes 'PlainTextDocument', 'TextDocument', 'character'  atomic [1:1] Developing assessment models   Developing models
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "Author")= chr "John Smith"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "DateTimeStamp")= POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2013-04-30 12:03:49"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "Description")= chr(0) 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "Heading")= chr "Research Focus"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "ID")= chr(0) 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "Language")= chr(0) 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "LocalMetaData")=List of 4
  .. .. .. ..$ foo           : chr "bar"
  .. .. .. ..$ classification: chr "Technician"
  .. .. .. ..$ team          : chr ""
  .. .. .. ..$ supervisor    : chr "Bill Jones"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "Origin")= chr "Smith-John_e.txt"

#etc., all sublists have 6 elements
```

So, to get all my `PlainTextDocument`s into a `Corpus`, this would work:

```
sectioned.Corpus <- c(sectioned[[1]][[1]], sectioned[[1]][[2]], ..., sectioned[[154]][[6]])
```

Can anyone suggest an easier way, please?

ETA: `foo<-unlist(foolist, recursive=FALSE)` produces a flat list of PlainTextDocuments, which still leaves me with the problem of feeding a list element by element to `c`

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I expect that `unlist(foolist)` will help you. It has an option `recursive` which is `TRUE` by default.

So `unlist(foolist, recursive = FALSE)` will return the list of the documents, and then you can combine them by:

```
do.call(c, unlist(foolist, recursive=FALSE))
```

`do.call` just applies the function `c` to the elements of the obtained list

Comment: Also consider using `NCmisc::Unlist()` for unlisting beyond the first level.

Comment: @zx8754 for the very similar large list, after importing a json file, I'm applying the same code, but I get the error "unlist arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0", which I understand, but i thought the code deals with lists of different levels. Any ideas? Beginner R user here... Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @choabf, I advise you to create a new question, where put an example of your data and code you used.

Answer (score 34):

Here's a more general solution for when lists are nested multiple times and the amount of nesting differs between elements of the lists:

```
 flattenlist <- function(x){  
  morelists <- sapply(x, function(xprime) class(xprime)[1]=="list")
  out <- c(x[!morelists], unlist(x[morelists], recursive=FALSE))
  if(sum(morelists)){ 
    Recall(out)
  }else{
    return(out)
  }
}
```

Comment: just to make this a bit more comprehensible I'll just point out that identifying lists using class(xprime)[1]=="list") is necessary (rather than using is.list) when your nested objects are of classes that inherit from lists (i.e. note that is.list(data.frame(3)) evaluates to TRUE)

Comment: also note that this doesn't retain the order of the original structure

Comment: Michael, how would you go about retaining the order of the original structure?

Comment: probably just replace `out <- c(` with an `mapply` statement that takes `x` and `morelists` as arguments then unlists only for elements where `morelists` is TRUE

Comment: or replace the first two lines with a single `lapply` that combines testing and unlisting

Comment: Very useful: My usecase is `map(some_nested_list, flattenlist) %>% bind_rows()` to produce a tibble.

Answer (score 12):

Here's another method that worked for my list of lists.

`df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(foolist, as.data.frame)))`

Or take a look at new functions in tidyr which work well.

[rectangle a nested list into a tidy tibble](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/hoist.html)

[rectangling](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rectangle.html)

```
    lst <-  list(
      list(
        age = 23,
        gender = "Male",
        city = "Sydney"
      ),
      list(
        age = 21,
        gender = "Female",
        city = "Cairns"
      )
    )
      
    tib <- tibble(lst)  %>% 
      unnest_wider(lst)

df <- as.data.frame(tib)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. ```unnest_wider``` from the tidyr package worked perfectly. The other code you posted gave me an error message "Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :  names do not match previous names"  --> The data I am working with is downloaded as a JSON from Facebook. It is highly nested. Not all lists in the list are equally long. The data structure also varies between downloaded files.

Comment: @Simone, I think you should post a new question with a simple replication of your data, then some can try to help you. SO doesn't like questions within questions

Comment: I [did](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69838172/revisions). Wanted to point out that there are "normally" nested lists and highly nested lists. For the latter the tidyr package is useful. --> hence the comment and not a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reduce:

```r
flatt <- 
\ (xss, flatf = c) 
    xss |> Reduce (\(a,b) flatf (a,b) , x = _)
```

Demo:

```r
list (list (1,0,3),list (2,4),list (3,6,5)) -> src

src |> flatt(c)
# or
src |> flatt()
```

It will give a result same as `list (1,0,3,2,4,3,6,5)`, means `c(c(list (1,0,3), list (2,4)), list (3,6,5))` here.

You can try them at this *[webr playground](https://webr.r-wasm.org)*.