# R : Convert nested list into a one level list

Tags: r, list

I got the following y nested list :

```
x1=c(12,54,2)
x2=c(2,88,1)
x3=c(4,8)

y=list()
y[[1]]=x1
y[[2]]=list(x2,x3)

y
[[1]]
[1] 12 54  2

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1]  2 88  1

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 4 8
```

I would like to extract all elements from this nested list and put them into a one level list, so my expected result should be :

```
y_one_level_list
[[1]]
[1] 12 54  2

[[2]]
[1]  2 88  1

[[3]]
[1] 4 8
```

Obviously ma real problem involve a deeper nested list, how would you solve it? I tried rapply but I failed.

Comment: Use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41882883/7128934).

Comment: @d.b unfortunately, no, I did look this post and it does not produce the expected results.

Comment: @d.b Yes your first post does work!!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: [These solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443179/flatten-nested-lists-in-a-list/48443290#48443290) also work and preserve the structure of my data better

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try `lapply` together with `rapply`:

```
lapply(rapply(y, enquote, how="unlist"), eval)

#[[1]]
#[1] 12 54  2

#[[2]]
#[1]  2 88  1

#[[3]]
#[1] 4 8
```

It does work for deeper lists either.

Comment: Yeaaah It also works, more elegant way to do it thanks

Comment: excellent solution! FYI.  https://www.r-bloggers.com/rapply-function-explanation-and-examples/

Comment: what is the `eval` doing at the end?

Comment: Some explanation would also be nice. What are `enquote` and `eval` @989?

Comment: `?enquote` states that: `enquote is a simple one-line utility which transforms a call of the form Foo(....) into the call quote(Foo(....))`. Then, `eval(quote(c(4,8)))`, for instance, returns a vector containing `4,8`

Comment: Thanks. The other [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443179/flatten-nested-lists-in-a-list) did not work for me

Answer (score 8):

You can try this:

```
flatten <- function(lst) {
    do.call(c, lapply(lst, function(x) if(is.list(x)) flatten(x) else list(x)))
}

flatten(y)

#[[1]]
#[1] 12 54  2

#[[2]]
#[1]  2 88  1

#[[3]]
#[1] 4 8
```

Comment: funny i think this one is simpler.