# Flatten nested lists in a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list with nested lists inside.

```
LIST2 <- list(list("USA","WY","TX","AZ","Canada", "CA", "NY", 'Russia', 'NY'), 
             list(c("USA","Canada","CA","WY", 'China', 'AZ', 'AZ', 'AZ', 'WY')), 
             list(c("USA","Australia","CA","AR", 'AZ', 'WY', 'New Zealand', 'Japan', 'Japan', 'NJ')),
             list(list('Australia', 'Australia', 'Japan', 'Malaysia' )),
             list(c('USA', 'Australia', 'Japan', 'Malaysia' )))
```

I would like to *flatten* somehow the 1st and 4th list so they are same form as the rest of them. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe `lapply(LIST2, function(i) list(unlist(i, recursive = TRUE)))
` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Loop through the list, unlist recursively, then return as a list:

```
lapply(LIST2, function(i) list(unlist(i, recursive = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 17):

We could use `rapply`

```
lapply(LIST2, rapply, f = c)
```

Comment: Nice one, keep forgetting about rapply. I think OP wants output as list of lists.

Comment: @zx8754  Thanks, then wrapping with `list` as you have done would be the way to go `lapply(LIST2, function(x) list(rapply(x, f = c)))`

Comment: nice - also preserved the structure of my data better than [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739419/r-convert-nested-list-into-a-one-level-list) 
Not sure though why my output list is still nested one level deep.  But this is a small problem in comparison to my previous highly nested list with elements of unequal length

Answer (score 4):

this should do it for you:

```
LIST2 <- lapply(LIST2, unlist)
```