# Completely flatten highly nested lists of lists with rapply, purrr, tidyr

Tags: r, lapply, tidyr, purrr, nested-lists

Downloaded Facebook data gives me a head ache. It is highly nested (lists of list) and not all lists are equally long. The data should become a flat matrix where one list and its sublists are in one row, i.e. one list including its sublist per row. So far I have explored three options.

**Option 1: flatten from [purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/)**

Flattens the data structure but scrambles it. So no way of knowing what text was posted when with what kind of picture. According to the purrr [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/purrr.pdf), I cannot specify an object, e.g. timestamp, by which the lists should be flattened? I am thinking about the [reshape2 package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/reshape2/versions/1.4.4) that allows to define an ID variable by which the data is reshaped/manipulated.

```
library(RJSONIO)
#read in data with utf-8 encoding else the German Umlaute won't display
dataRAW <- RJSONIO::fromJSON("C:/***file path***/FB rot 2.json",
                    encoding = 'utf-8', stringAsFactors = F)

dataRAWflat <- purrr:::flatten(dataRAW) #scrambles data
```

--> I know that [jsonlite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/jsonlite.pdf) has a flatten function when reading in JSON files. But `fromJSON` from jsonlite does not allow to define the encoding. The encoding needs to be defined else it does not display the German Umlaute correctly. Also tried [rjson](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/rjson.pdf) without success. The text of the posts is key to the project. I spent a good amount of figuring out how to display the Umlaute so happy to help with that :-)

**Option 2: unnest_wider from [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/hoist.html)**
Gives an error message saying that it should be numeric or a character, but the list 'data' in dataRAW is a character. New to tibbles as a special kind of dataframe. Do tibbles, like dataframes, need to have equally long columns? What am I missing?

```
library(tibble)
tib <- tibble(dataRAW)
tib %>% tidyr:::unnest_wider(data)
Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has the wrong type `function`.
i It must be numeric or character.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/vctrs_error_subscript_type>
Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has the wrong type `function`.
i It must be numeric or character.
Backtrace:
  1. tib %>% tidyr:::unnest_wider(data)
  2. tidyr:::unnest_wider(., data)
  3. tidyselect::vars_pull(tbl_vars(data), !!enquo(col))
  4. tidyselect:::pull_as_location2(loc, n, vars)
 12. vctrs::vec_as_subscript2(i, arg = "var", logical = "error")
 13. vctrs:::result_get(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
> rlang:::last_trace()
<error/vctrs_error_subscript_type>
Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has the wrong type `function`.
i It must be numeric or character.
Backtrace:
     x
  1. +-tib %>% tidyr:::unnest_wider(data)
  2. \-tidyr:::unnest_wider(., data)
  3.   \-tidyselect::vars_pull(tbl_vars(data), !!enquo(col))
  4.     \-tidyselect:::pull_as_location2(loc, n, vars)
  5.       +-tidyselect:::with_subscript_errors(...)
  6.       | +-base::tryCatch(...)
  7.       | | \-base:::tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
  8.       | |   \-base:::tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
  9.       | |     \-base:::doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 10.       | \-tidyselect:::instrument_base_errors(expr)
 11.       |   \-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 12.       \-vctrs::vec_as_subscript2(i, arg = "var", logical = "error")
 13.         \-vctrs:::result_get(...)
```

**Option 3: [rapply and lapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443179/flatten-nested-lists-in-a-list/48443290#48443290)**
Both code snippets work and preserve the data structure. When I want to convert the data to a matrix for further processing the data structure is messed up. I suspect because the data is still nested one level deep.

```
#code line returns list nested one level deep
FBraw <- lapply(dataRAW, rapply, f = c)
str(FBraw)
List of 40
 $ : Named chr [1:7] "1611853326" "posts/media/ChronikFotos_QNGAWvS8aw/144245114_3813727445333297_3682316138130576479_n_3813727441999964.jpg" "1611853319" "1613542113" ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "timestamp" "attachments.data.media.uri" "attachments.data.media.creation_timestamp" "attachments.data.media.media_metadata.photo_metadata.exif_data.taken_timestamp" ...
 $ : Named chr [1:7] "1611860575" "posts/media/ChronikFotos_QNGAWvS8aw/143276316_3813978641974844_3663341405860849380_n_3813978635308178.png" "1611860403" "1612935033" ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "timestamp" "attachments.data.media.uri" "attachments.data.media.creation_timestamp" "attachments.data.media.media_metadata.photo_metadata.exif_data.taken_timestamp" ...
 $ : Named chr [1:7] "1612948020" "posts/media/ChronikFotos_QNGAWvS8aw/143732770_3813831571989551_5247994518213519901_n_3813831568656218.png" "1611856188" "1617631305" ...

#code snippet 2 
FBraw <- lapply(dataRAW, function(x) data.frame(t(rapply(x, function(x) x[1]))))
str(FBraw, head = 1)
List of 40
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  7 variables:
```

**Sample Data**

```
dataRAW <- list(
  list(
    timestamp = 1611853326, attachments = list(list(data = list(
      list(media = list(
        uri = "posts/media/ChronikFotos_QNGAWvS8aw/144245114_3813727445333297_3682316138130576479_n_3813727441999964.jpg",
        creation_timestamp = 1611853319, media_metadata = list(
          photo_metadata = list(exif_data = list(c(taken_timestamp = 1613542113)))
        ),
        title = "Chronik-Fotos", description = "Da haben wir den Salat! <U+0001F957> \nGemischt oder grün: Verfeinert mit Frieda’s Traum Salatsauce wird der einfachste Salat zum Gaumenschmaus.\n\nProbieren Sie auch unsere Gewürze, Bouillons und verschiedene Käse! \nHier finden Sie alle unsere würzigen Produkte:  www.friedas-traum.ch/\n\n<U+0001D46D><U+0001D493><U+0001D48A><U+0001D486><U+0001D485><U+0001D482>'<U+0001D494> <U+0001D47B><U+0001D493><U+0001D482><U+0001D496><U+0001D48E> – Saucen Bouillons Gewürze\nwww.friedas-traum.ch | shop@friedas.ch | Tel. 055 0"
      ))
    ))),
    data = list(post = 1)
  ),
  list(
    timestamp = 1611860575, attachments = list(list(data = list(
      list(media = list(
        uri = "posts/media/ChronikFotos_QNGAWvS8aw/143276316_3813978641974844_3663341405860849380_n_3813978635308178.png",
        creation_timestamp = 1611860403, media_metadata = list(
          photo_metadata = list(exif_data = list(c(taken_timestamp = 1612935033)))
        ),
        title = "Chronik-Fotos", description = "Früher über die Gasse – heute im Online- Shop: <U+0001D5D9><U+0001D5FF><U+0001D5F6><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D5F1><U+0001D5EE>’<U+0001D600> <U+0001D5E7><U+0001D5FF><U+0001D5EE><U+0001D602><U+0001D5FA> Produkte. \n\nWas im Restaurant Löwen in Spreitenbach begann, geht heute online weiter: Sie erhalten 100% Geschmack!\n\nEinfach bestellen im Shop: www.friedas-traum.ch/\n\n<U+0001D46D><U+0001D493><U+0001D48A><U+0001D486><U+0001D485><U+0001D482>’<U+0001D494> <U+0001D47B><U+0001D493><U+0001D482><U+0001D496><U+0001D48E> – Saucen, Bouillons, Gewürze\nshop@friedas.ch  | Tel. +41 (0) 55 0"
      ))
    ))),
    data = list(c(post = "Früher über die Gasse – heute im Online- Shop: <U+0001D5D9><U+0001D5FF><U+0001D5F6><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D5F1><U+0001D5EE>’<U+0001D600> <U+0001D5E7><U+0001D5FF><U+0001D5EE><U+0001D602><U+0001D5FA> Produkte. \n\nWas im Restaurant Löwen in Spreitenbach begann, geht heute online weiter: Sie erhalten 100% Geschmack!\n\nEinfach bestellen im Shop: www.friedas-traum.ch/\n\n<U+0001D46D><U+0001D493><U+0001D48A><U+0001D486><U+0001D485><U+0001D482>’<U+0001D494> <U+0001D47B><U+0001D493><U+0001D482><U+0001D496><U+0001D48E> – Saucen, Bouillons, Gewürze\nshop@friedas.ch  | Tel. +41 (0) 55 0"))
  ),
  list(
    timestamp = 1612948020, attachments = list(list(data = list(
      list(media = list(
        uri = "posts/media/ChronikFotos_QNGAWvS8aw/143732770_3813831571989551_5247994518213519901_n_3813831568656218.png",
        creation_timestamp = 1611856188, media_metadata = list(
          photo_metadata = list(exif_data = list(c(taken_timestamp = 1617631305)))
        ),
        title = "Chronik-Fotos", description = "<U+0001D5E1><U+0001D5EE><U+0001D5F0><U+0001D5F5> <U+0001D5EE><U+0001D5F9><U+0001D601><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D5FA> <U+0001D5E5><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D607><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D5FD><U+0001D601> von Hand gemischt und abgefüllt: Frieda’s Salatsaucen sind beliebt wie eh und je. <U+0001F44C>\n\nFrüher der Renner im Restaurant Löwen in Spreitenbach, heute: DER Hit zum Bestellen für Sie zu Hause.\n\nProbieren Sie auch unsere Bouillons, Gewürze und unseren Käse! \n\nHier geht’s zum Shop:  www.friedas-traum.ch/\n\n<U+0001D46D><U+0001D493><U+0001D48A><U+0001D486><U+0001D485><U+0001D482>’<U+0001D494> <U+0001D47B><U+0001D493><U+0001D482><U+0001D496><U+0001D48E>® – Saucen Bouillons Gewürze\nshop@friedas.ch | Tel. 055 0"
      ))
    ))),
    data = list(c(post = "<U+0001D5E1><U+0001D5EE><U+0001D5F0><U+0001D5F5> <U+0001D5EE><U+0001D5F9><U+0001D601><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D5FA> <U+0001D5E5><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D607><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D5FD><U+0001D601> von Hand gemischt und abgefüllt: Frieda’s Salatsaucen sind beliebt wie eh und je. <U+0001F44C>\n\nFrüher der Renner im Restaurant Löwen in Spreitenbach, heute: DER Hit zum Bestellen für Sie zu Hause.\n\nProbieren Sie auch unsere Bouillons, Gewürze und unseren Käse! \n\nHier geht’s zum Shop:  www.friedas-traum.ch/\n\n<U+0001D46D><U+0001D493><U+0001D48A><U+0001D486><U+0001D485><U+0001D482>’<U+0001D494> <U+0001D47B><U+0001D493><U+0001D482><U+0001D496><U+0001D48E>® – Saucen Bouillons Gewürze\nshop@friedas.ch | Tel. 055 0"))
  )
)
```

Any ideas and suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Grothendick thought that the data sample could be easily copied and pasted to create a reproducible example. I knew of dput(x) - it prints out all the data making it a) confusing and b) creates privacy troubles. I am working with personal data. Will add a data sample in form of a file. Have not found a way to [dput the first 3 lists](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput) only?

Comment: or `library(rrapply)
rrapply(X, f = head, n = 6, dfaslist = FALSE)` to preserve list structure, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64794738/dput-a-long-list-shorten-list-but-preserve-structure)

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thanks for the suggestion. It prints out half the data... ;-)  Hope the sample data download works?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck did a manual selection of dput() output.

Comment: @user63230 thanks for sharing. Code outputs all data points. Also gives a warning message ```In rrapply(dataRAW, f = head, n = 3, dfaslist = FALSE) :  'dfaslist' is deprecated, use classes = 'data.frame' instead ``` - any ways data sample question is fixed now.

Comment: @Simone I revised my answer to use your example data instead of mine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of elements which have the same properties (e.g. `timestamps` and `attachments`). Since these are of different types, you can use a data frame instead of a matrix by *enframing* the list.
Please note the element data which can be either (the first entry) a number or a character (otherwise).
We need to enforce the same class required to put these elements into one column using `as.character`.
Doing so, numbers will be converted to characters.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dataRAW <- list(
  list(
    timestamp = 1611853326, attachments = list(list(data = list(
      list(media = list(
        uri = "posts/media/ChronikFotos_QNGAWvS8aw/144245114_3813727445333297_3682316138130576479_n_3813727441999964.jpg",
        creation_timestamp = 1611853319, media_metadata = list(
          photo_metadata = list(exif_data = list(c(taken_timestamp = 1613542113)))
        ),
        title = "Chronik-Fotos", description = "Da haben wir den Salat! <U+0001F957> \nGemischt oder grün: Verfeinert mit Frieda’s Traum Salatsauce wird der einfachste Salat zum Gaumenschmaus.\n\nProbieren Sie auch unsere Gewürze, Bouillons und verschiedene Käse! \nHier finden Sie alle unsere würzigen Produkte:  www.friedas-traum.ch/\n\n<U+0001D46D><U+0001D493><U+0001D48A><U+0001D486><U+0001D485><U+0001D482>'<U+0001D494> <U+0001D47B><U+0001D493><U+0001D482><U+0001D496><U+0001D48E> – Saucen Bouillons Gewürze\nwww.friedas-traum.ch | shop@friedas.ch | Tel. 055 0"
      ))
    ))),
    data = list(post = 1)
  ),
  list(
    timestamp = 1611860575, attachments = list(list(data = list(
      list(media = list(
        uri = "posts/media/ChronikFotos_QNGAWvS8aw/143276316_3813978641974844_3663341405860849380_n_3813978635308178.png",
        creation_timestamp = 1611860403, media_metadata = list(
          photo_metadata = list(exif_data = list(c(taken_timestamp = 1612935033)))
        ),
        title = "Chronik-Fotos", description = "Früher über die Gasse – heute im Online- Shop: <U+0001D5D9><U+0001D5FF><U+0001D5F6><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D5F1><U+0001D5EE>’<U+0001D600> <U+0001D5E7><U+0001D5FF><U+0001D5EE><U+0001D602><U+0001D5FA> Produkte. \n\nWas im Restaurant Löwen in Spreitenbach begann, geht heute online weiter: Sie erhalten 100% Geschmack!\n\nEinfach bestellen im Shop: www.friedas-traum.ch/\n\n<U+0001D46D><U+0001D493><U+0001D48A><U+0001D486><U+0001D485><U+0001D482>’<U+0001D494> <U+0001D47B><U+0001D493><U+0001D482><U+0001D496><U+0001D48E> – Saucen, Bouillons, Gewürze\nshop@friedas.ch  | Tel. +41 (0) 55 0"
      ))
    ))),
    data = list(c(post = "Früher über die Gasse – heute im Online- Shop: <U+0001D5D9><U+0001D5FF><U+0001D5F6><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D5F1><U+0001D5EE>’<U+0001D600> <U+0001D5E7><U+0001D5FF><U+0001D5EE><U+0001D602><U+0001D5FA> Produkte. \n\nWas im Restaurant Löwen in Spreitenbach begann, geht heute online weiter: Sie erhalten 100% Geschmack!\n\nEinfach bestellen im Shop: www.friedas-traum.ch/\n\n<U+0001D46D><U+0001D493><U+0001D48A><U+0001D486><U+0001D485><U+0001D482>’<U+0001D494> <U+0001D47B><U+0001D493><U+0001D482><U+0001D496><U+0001D48E> – Saucen, Bouillons, Gewürze\nshop@friedas.ch  | Tel. +41 (0) 55 0"))
  ),
  list(
    timestamp = 1612948020, attachments = list(list(data = list(
      list(media = list(
        uri = "posts/media/ChronikFotos_QNGAWvS8aw/143732770_3813831571989551_5247994518213519901_n_3813831568656218.png",
        creation_timestamp = 1611856188, media_metadata = list(
          photo_metadata = list(exif_data = list(c(taken_timestamp = 1617631305)))
        ),
        title = "Chronik-Fotos", description = "<U+0001D5E1><U+0001D5EE><U+0001D5F0><U+0001D5F5> <U+0001D5EE><U+0001D5F9><U+0001D601><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D5FA> <U+0001D5E5><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D607><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D5FD><U+0001D601> von Hand gemischt und abgefüllt: Frieda’s Salatsaucen sind beliebt wie eh und je. <U+0001F44C>\n\nFrüher der Renner im Restaurant Löwen in Spreitenbach, heute: DER Hit zum Bestellen für Sie zu Hause.\n\nProbieren Sie auch unsere Bouillons, Gewürze und unseren Käse! \n\nHier geht’s zum Shop:  www.friedas-traum.ch/\n\n<U+0001D46D><U+0001D493><U+0001D48A><U+0001D486><U+0001D485><U+0001D482>’<U+0001D494> <U+0001D47B><U+0001D493><U+0001D482><U+0001D496><U+0001D48E>® – Saucen Bouillons Gewürze\nshop@friedas.ch | Tel. 055 0"
      ))
    ))),
    data = list(c(post = "<U+0001D5E1><U+0001D5EE><U+0001D5F0><U+0001D5F5> <U+0001D5EE><U+0001D5F9><U+0001D601><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D5FA> <U+0001D5E5><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D607><U+0001D5F2><U+0001D5FD><U+0001D601> von Hand gemischt und abgefüllt: Frieda’s Salatsaucen sind beliebt wie eh und je. <U+0001F44C>\n\nFrüher der Renner im Restaurant Löwen in Spreitenbach, heute: DER Hit zum Bestellen für Sie zu Hause.\n\nProbieren Sie auch unsere Bouillons, Gewürze und unseren Käse! \n\nHier geht’s zum Shop:  www.friedas-traum.ch/\n\n<U+0001D46D><U+0001D493><U+0001D48A><U+0001D486><U+0001D485><U+0001D482>’<U+0001D494> <U+0001D47B><U+0001D493><U+0001D482><U+0001D496><U+0001D48E>® – Saucen Bouillons Gewürze\nshop@friedas.ch | Tel. 055 0"))
  )
)

dataRAW %>%
  enframe()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>    name value           
#>   <int> <list>          
#> 1     1 <named list [3]>
#> 2     2 <named list [3]>
#> 3     3 <named list [3]>

dataRAW %>%
  enframe() %>%
  unnest_wider(value)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>    name  timestamp attachments data            
#>   <int>      <dbl> <list>      <list>          
#> 1     1 1611853326 <list [1]>  <named list [1]>
#> 2     2 1611860575 <list [1]>  <list [1]>      
#> 3     3 1612948020 <list [1]>  <list [1]>

dataRAW %>%
  enframe() %>%
  unnest_wider(value) %>%
  # flatten list with only one element
  unnest(data) %>%
  # Enforce data to have the same type
  mutate(data = data %>% as.character()) %>%
  unnest(data) %>%
  unnest(attachments) %>%
  unnest(attachments) %>%
  unnest(attachments) %>%
  unnest(attachments) %>%
  unnest_wider(attachments) %>%
  select(name, timestamp, creation_timestamp, title, data)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>    name  timestamp creation_timestamp title         data                        
#>   <int>      <dbl>              <dbl> <chr>         <chr>                       
#> 1     1 1611853326         1611853319 Chronik-Fotos "1"                         
#> 2     2 1611860575         1611860403 Chronik-Fotos "Früher über die Gasse – he…
#> 3     3 1612948020         1611856188 Chronik-Fotos "<U+0001D5E1><U+0001D5EE><U…
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks let me try this out

Comment: The code works until line 4, i.e. the second ```unnest(value)```. Then it gives me an error Error: 
Can't combine `..1$data` <character> and `..20$data` <double>.
Backtrace:
  1. `%>%`(...)
3. tidyr:::unnest.data.frame(., data)
4. tidyr::unchop(data, any_of(cols), keep_empty = keep_empty, ptype = ptype)
5. tidyr:::df_unchop_info(cols, ptype)
6. vctrs::vec_unchop(pieces, ptype = col_ptype)
8. vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
9. vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
10. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
11. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)

Comment: @Simone I edited the example data and my answer to fix the problem

Comment: it throws an error at line 11 ```unnest_wider(attachments)```saying ```Error: Can't combine `..1$uri` <list> and `..30$uri` <character>.```  **Backtrace**:
  1. `%>%`(...)
  2. tidyr::unnest_wider(., attachments, names_repair = "unique")
  3. tidyr::unchop(data, any_of(col), keep_empty = TRUE)
  4. tidyr:::df_unchop_info(cols, ptype)
  5. vctrs::vec_unchop(pieces, ptype = col_ptype)
  7. vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
  8. vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
  9. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
 10. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)

Comment: You need to unify the types of `attachments` in the same way it is done for `data`. Do you have always one `data` element and sometimes many `attachments` per post?, Then create multiple rows instead of multiple columns using `unnest(attachments)` instead of `unnest_wider(attachments)`

Comment: tried it out with the data sample I provided on SO instead of data I have. The code ran through but it did not flatten the data? ```dataRAW$name``` or ```dataRAW[ ,"name"]``` return NULL and error message respectively but this is [how to access elements in tibbles](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/subsetting.html)

Comment: The data structure changes in at least 2 ways: **A)** the top-level list has no sublist *attachments*. **B)** the sub^4-list *media* in the sublist *attachments* has sometimes a sublist *thumbnail*. Sometimes not. ...I am starting to think that maybe it is easiest to just retrieve the posts? Saw the [tidyjson package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyjson/vignettes/introduction-to-tidyjson.html)

Comment: There is a reason why Facebook gives you the json: There are elements of different types with different properties (e.g. post with properties data and timestamp and another type called attachment with properties like thumbnail). A table is meant to show elements of one spectic type. Dou you want to have a table of attachments and another table of post_contents ?

Comment: haha - thought about that today and last week too. Yes Facebook *has* to give me my data according to GDPR,  but they sure make it hard to work with it. As a minimum requirement I need the posts text. Working also with JSON files from other Facebook accounts (ppl give me their own downloaded data) with yet a different data structure. :-/ Though the *list names* remain the same

Comment: the alternative is a HTML file from where I need to collect all the appropriate fields. Not sure if that is better? Not experience with reading in HTML in R.

Comment: HTML is internal a tree structure as well. It's to the scientific definition of a table that we should not use a table to describe objects of different classes.