# Create list from vector based on given structure / list

Tags: r, list

After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14656351/1114975), I was confident that `relist()` should work to reconstruct a list in the following example:

```
a <- c("AA01_01", "AA01_03", "AA01_04", "AA01_06", "AA01_08", "AA01_11", "AA01_12", "AA01_13",
    "AA01_14", "AA01_16", "AA01_19", "AA01_20", "AA02_03", "AA02_04", "AA02_05", "AA02_06", "AA02_07",
    "AA02_08", "AA02_09", "AA02_13", "AA02_17", "AA02_19", "AA02_20", "AA03_05", "AA03_09", "AA03_10",
    "AA03_12", "AA03_16", "AA03_20", "AA04_01", "AA04_02", "AA04_03", "AA04_10", "AA04_11", "AA04_14",
    "AA04_16"
)

b <- list(
    b1 = c("AA01_01", "AA01_02", "AA01_03", "AA01_04", "AA01_05", "AA01_06", "AA01_07", "AA01_08", "AA01_09", "AA01_10",
        "AA01_11", "AA01_12", "AA01_13", "AA01_14", "AA01_15", "AA01_16", "AA01_17", "AA01_18", "AA01_19", "AA01_20"),
    b2 = c("AA02_01", "AA02_02", "AA02_03", "AA02_04", "AA02_05", "AA02_06", "AA02_07", "AA02_08", "AA02_09", "AA02_10",
        "AA02_11", "AA02_12", "AA02_13", "AA02_14", "AA02_15", "AA02_16", "AA02_17", "AA02_18", "AA02_19", "AA02_20"),
    b3 = c("AA03_01", "AA03_02", "AA03_03", "AA03_04", "AA03_05", "AA03_06", "AA03_07", "AA03_08", "AA03_09", "AA03_10",
        "AA03_11", "AA03_12", "AA03_13", "AA03_14", "AA03_15", "AA03_16", "AA03_17", "AA03_18", "AA03_19", "AA03_20"),
    b4 = c("AA04_01", "AA04_02", "AA04_03", "AA04_04", "AA04_05", "AA04_06", "AA04_07", "AA04_08", "AA04_09", "AA04_10",
        "AA04_11", "AA04_12", "AA04_13", "AA04_14", "AA04_15", "AA04_16", "AA04_17", "AA04_18", "AA04_19", "AA04_20")
)

newList <- relist(flesh = a, skeleton = b)
```

According to `?relist()`, this should result in `newList$b1` containing all characters starting with `AA01_`, `newList$b2` should contain `AA02_`, and so on... but what I get is:

```
$b1
 [1] "AA01_01" "AA01_03" "AA01_04" "AA01_06" "AA01_08" "AA01_11" "AA01_12" "AA01_13" "AA01_14" "AA01_16" "AA01_19" "AA01_20" "AA02_03" "AA02_04"
[15] "AA02_05" "AA02_06" "AA02_07" "AA02_08" "AA02_09" "AA02_13"

$b2
 [1] "AA02_17" "AA02_19" "AA02_20" "AA03_05" "AA03_09" "AA03_10" "AA03_12" "AA03_16" "AA03_20" "AA04_01" "AA04_02" "AA04_03" "AA04_10" "AA04_11"
[15] "AA04_14" "AA04_16" NA        NA        NA        NA       

$b3
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

$b4
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Why does this happen and how should I proceed to create a list from a vector based on a model-list?

**EDIT:** As mentioned by @OganM in the comments, `relist()` requires the same structure after the list has been altered. So i rephrase my question: **How can I create a list from a vector based on a structure of another list?** I would prefer a solution that also works for nested lists.

Comment: a has less elements than b has so it cannot be relisted. the purpose of relist is to use it after `a = unlist(b)` so that you can modify a and re-create the structure of b later. If you remove elements from a, the same structure cannot be acquired again since you don't know how to break apart the list anymore. Here, you see that in conservatively tries to fill the first 2 elements and `NA`s the rest

Comment: I see, thanks. Then `relist()` was apparently not what I was looking for. Is there an alternative function that will accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57448008/how-to-create-all-combinations-from-a-nested-list-while-preserving-the-structure

Comment: Are you trying to find elements in `b` which are common to `a` ? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lapply(b, function(x) a[a %in% x])
#$b1
# [1] "AA01_01" "AA01_03" "AA01_04" "AA01_06" "AA01_08" "AA01_11" "AA01_12" "AA01_13"
# [9] "AA01_14" "AA01_16" "AA01_19" "AA01_20"

#$b2
# [1] "AA02_03" "AA02_04" "AA02_05" "AA02_06" "AA02_07" "AA02_08" "AA02_09" "AA02_13"
# [9] "AA02_17" "AA02_19" "AA02_20"

#$b3
#[1] "AA03_05" "AA03_09" "AA03_10" "AA03_12" "AA03_16" "AA03_20"

#$b4
#[1] "AA04_01" "AA04_02" "AA04_03" "AA04_10" "AA04_11" "AA04_14" "AA04_16"
```

Recursion might be necessary for nested lists

```r
# Recursive function
foo = function(l, vect) {
    for (i in seq_along(l)) {
        l[[i]] = if (class(l[[i]]) == "list") {
            Recall(l[[i]], vect)
        } else {
            vect[ vect %in% l[[i]] ]
        }
    }
    return(l)
}

#DATA (nested list)
a = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
b = list(b1 = c("a", "b", "g", "h"),
         b2 = list(b21 = c("a", "d", "y"),
                   b22 = "f"))

# Usage
foo(b, a)
#> $b1
#> [1] "a" "b"
#> 
#> $b2
#> $b2$b21
#> [1] "a" "d"
#> 
#> $b2$b22
#> [1] "f"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Or an option in `tidyverse` `map(b, keep, `%in%`, a)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find elements in `a` which are present in `b` you could use `intersect`

```
lapply(b, intersect, a)


#$b1
# [1] "AA01_01" "AA01_03" "AA01_04" "AA01_06" "AA01_08" "AA01_11" "AA01_12" 
#     "AA01_13" "AA01_14" "AA01_16" "AA01_19" "AA01_20"

#$b2
# [1] "AA02_03" "AA02_04" "AA02_05" "AA02_06" "AA02_07" "AA02_08" "AA02_09"  
#     "AA02_13" "AA02_17" "AA02_19" "AA02_20"

#$b3
#[1] "AA03_05" "AA03_09" "AA03_10" "AA03_12" "AA03_16" "AA03_20"

#$b4
#[1] "AA04_01" "AA04_02" "AA04_03" "AA04_10" "AA04_11" "AA04_14" "AA04_16"
```

Comment: yes, it will. couldn't find any duplicates in OP's sample data though.